# Cannot get transaction's field "From" using Golang

Tags: go-ethereum, golang

How I can get transaction's field "From"?

```
client, err := ethclient.Dial("https://mainnet.infura.io")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

blockNumber := big.NewInt(5671744)
block, err := client.BlockByNumber(context.Background(), blockNumber)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

for _, tx := range block.Transactions() {
    fmt.Println(tx.Hash().Hex())        // 0x5d49fcaa394c97ec8a9c3e7bd9e8388d420fb050a52083ca52ff24b3b65bc9c2
    fmt.Println(tx.Value().String())    // 10000000000000000
    fmt.Println(tx.Gas())               // 105000
    fmt.Println(tx.GasPrice().Uint64()) // 102000000000
    fmt.Println(tx.Nonce())             // 110644
    fmt.Println(tx.Data())              // []
    fmt.Println(tx.To().Hex())          // 0x55fE59D8Ad77035154dDd0AD0388D09Dd4047A8e

    if msg, err := tx.AsMessage(types.HomesteadSigner{}); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(msg.From().Hex()) // 0x0fD081e3Bb178dc45c0cb23202069ddA57064258
    }
}
```

This code don't show it.

For instance, for transaction https://etherscan.io/tx/0x5d49fcaa394c97ec8a9c3e7bd9e8388d420fb050a52083ca52ff24b3b65bc9c2 it shows nothing.

For transaction https://etherscan.io/tx/0x36368eb4665367100bcb46427e8ac39b7873abfca2015116c478f84642a8812d it shows 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Comment: what if we use `types.EIP155Signer` instead of `types.HomesteadSigner` ?

Comment: @HaĐANG didn't help. Moreover, I trying to detect signer by transaction's block number:

signer := types.MakeSigner(&s.ChainConfig, big.NewInt(blockNumber))

and it it don't work too.

Comment: Can you post the full source code then I can run on my local? Thanks!

Comment: @HaĐANG
https://github.com/miguelmota/ethereum-development-with-go-book/blob/master/code/transactions.go

What I have as result for first transaction:
0x5d49fcaa394c97ec8a9c3e7bd9e8388d420fb050a52083ca52ff24b3b65bc9c2
10000000000000000
105000
102000000000
110644
[]
0x55fE59D8Ad77035154dDd0AD0388D09Dd4047A8e
1

What I expect:

0x5d49fcaa394c97ec8a9c3e7bd9e8388d420fb050a52083ca52ff24b3b65bc9c2
10000000000000000
105000
102000000000
110644
[]
0x55fE59D8Ad77035154dDd0AD0388D09Dd4047A8e
**0x0fd081e3bb178dc45c0cb23202069dda57064258** <- field "from"
1

Comment: okay, one more thing I want to confirm that you dont put the api key in the code for security purpose right? `client, err := ethclient.Dial("https://mainnet.infura.io")`. Because infura provide us an API key to access the end-point and i'm sure that you put it into the code when you running your program.

Comment: the correct infura end-point should be similar to `https://mainnet.infura.io/5rhaTHgnqnbTEFj1S1Ya`

Comment: @HaĐANG I use it with my own geth-node url. Result is the same.

Comment: please check my answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's one mistake in your code then you cannot printout the `from`

just replace this code

```
if msg, err := tx.AsMessage(types.HomesteadSigner{}); err != nil {
```

to

```
if msg, err := tx.AsMessage(types.HomesteadSigner{}); err == nil {
```

And we may need to use `tx.AsMessage(types.NewEIP155Signer(big.NewInt(1)))` for the mainnet instead of using `tx.AsMessage(types.HomesteadSigner{})`

Hope this help!

Comment: oh, yes, thanks. It helped for first two transactions. But for third transaction 0x36368eb4665367100bcb46427e8ac39b7873abfca2015116c478f84642a8812d from block 5671744 still no "from" field

Comment: yep, it report error `invalid transaction v, r, s values`; it seems that we need to make correct Signer for each tnx

Comment: if I use `tx.AsMessage(types.NewEIP155Signer(big.NewInt(1)))` then we can get correct `From` for tnx 3

Comment: Great, it really helped! Thank you!
P.S. By the way I try to make a signer with
chainConfig := params.ChainConfig{ChainID: big.NewInt(1)}
signer := types.MakeSigner(&chainConfig, blockNumber)
and then
tx.AsMessage(signer)
but it didn't help. May be it can be more correct way.

Comment: you need to add `EIP155Block` into the params.ChainConfig{} also to make it work properly